# Boot into Windows from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I'm running a system with dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 with GRUB2.

By default it's booting into Linux. I've set the PC to WoL so I can wake it up remotely. What I want is to run some command from Linux that will allow me to boot into Windows on *next* boot, but leaves the default boot option set to Linux.

Does any such program exist?

Comment: Have a look into        `grub-reboot - set the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only`

Comment: @RudiC why not formulate that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On special request (comment by Bruni, thanks):

Have a look into `grub-reboot` - set the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only